# Prevent premature garbage collection

Tags: java, c++, garbage-collection, java-native-interface, swig

I have an issues with premature garbage collection. I've found a nice [solution](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Java.html#Java_memory_management_objects) in SWIG documentation for solving such kind of issues. But I've faced with problem since I have static factory method from which non-static reference field can't be accessible.

Applying recommended SWIG solution to C++ code below

```
struct Child {
};

struct Parent {
  static Parent* create(Child& child);
};
```

gets broken Java code like

```
public static Parent create(Child child) {
  long cPtr = SampleJNI.Parent_create(getCPtrAndAddReference(child), child);
  return (cPtr == 0) ? null : new Parent(cPtr, false);
}
```

This code is broken since `Parent.create(Child child)` is static but `Parent.getCPtrAndAddReference(Child child)` is not. I'm thinking about one of two solutions.

The first one is find the way to generate something like

```
public static Parent create(Child child) {
  long cPtr = SampleJNI.Parent_create(Child.getCPtr(child), child);
  return (cPtr == 0) ? null : new Parent(cPtr, false, child)/* call of alternative constructor created with typmap(javabody) */;
}
```

but I don't know how to do it.

The second one solution is implement assignment on JNI side with `SetObjectField` call. I do know how to do it in general but I'd rather prefer the first solution if possible.

Comment: I have made interface file with only your structs, called `swig -c++ -java -outdir outdir -o wrapper.c -package com.example interface.i` (version 3.0.7, windows cygwin) and it generated right code: `long cPtr = exampleJNI.Parent_create(Child.getCPtr(child), child);`. It must be old swig version or other items from your interface file.

Comment: @V-master, thank you for the answer but I afraid you have misunderstood me. My goal is to cache `child` permanently not only during the `Parent_create` call.

Comment: You can hold on to a java object in C code with `NewGlobalRef`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @user2543253, yes it may be alternative of using `SetObjectField`. But it would be nice to solve the problem on the Java side since JNI solutions looks error-prone for me.

Comment: @user2543253, moreover `NewGlobalRef` implies using `DeleteGlobalRef` but I'd like to keep memory management on JVM as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
%newobject Parent::create;

%typemap(javacode) Parent %{
  private Child childReference;
%}

%typemap(javaout) Parent* create(Child&) {
    long cPtr = $jnicall;
    if (cPtr == 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        Parent p = new Parent(cPtr, $owner);
        p.childReference=child;
        return p;
    }
}
```

This will add field to `Parent` that will store reference to child, and save reference at point of creating.

`%newobject` says java to delete C object when garbage collecting this item. Don't forget about it, or you will have memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks, looks like what I'm was looking for. I've changed your solution a bit : `%typemap(javacode) B %{
  private A childReference;

  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  protected B(long cPtr, boolean cMemoryOwn, A childReference) {
    this(cPtr, cMemoryOwn);
    this.childReference = childReference;
  }
%}
%newobject B::create;
%typemap(javaout) B B::create(A* a) {
    long cPtr = $jnicall;
    return (cPtr == 0) ? null : new B(cPtr, $owner, a);
  }`