# How to use swig to modify class constructor to keep a reference to one of the constructor arguments?

Tags: python, c++, swig

Lets say I have a C++ class `MyArray(void* data, width, height)` and I want to wrap it with SWIG to Python. Now I have a typemap that maps a numpy array to data, width and height and I want to keep a MyArray object without copying, even if the numpy array goes out of scope.

How can I override/shadow the constructor of MyArray, to store a reference to the numpy array, so that the MyArray keeps a reference count of the numpy array?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that my solution for Java but I am sure there is no problems to convert to Python case. I've based my solution on other answer [Prevent premature garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33752220/prevent-premature-garbage-collection). In this approach reference to object stored in wrapper of high-level language (in your case Python). To do it you could use the next code in your `*.i` file (sample for Java-case):

```
%define SAVE_REF(container, variable)
%typemap(javacode) container %{
  private Object ref_ ## variable;
%}

%typemap(javaconstruct) container {
    ref_ ## variable = variable;
    swigCPtr = $imcall;
    swigCMemOwn = true;
}
%enddef
```

then before type declaration in `*.i`

```
SAVE_REF(my_awesome_container_t, element);

... type declaration ...
```